# Difficulty getting navbar to work

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a navbar using Bootstrap and I'm having trouble getting the dropdown menu to work.  I'm using JSFiddle to test it out

<s>https://jsfiddle.net/addlemanrachel/n9m8fjm8/#&togetherjs=nhtT9oahiE</s> edit: wrong link! Correct link is: https://jsfiddle.net/addlemanrachel/n9m8fjm8/.

Here is the  HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
          <li class="dropdown active">
            <a href='#' class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Community</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Recent Activity</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Member Activity</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Member List</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Member Groups</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Pet Help</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pets for Sale</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pet Services</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

At first I thought my issue was not linking jQuery but after doing that I still can't get it to work.  Thanks in advance for helping!  I'm so new at this and just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening your jsFiddle you can see you get the following error:

```
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

You get that error because jQuery is a Bootstrap dependency, so you have to make sure you are loading it correctly.

Including jQuery v2.2.3 in the jsfiddle you provided it now works

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n9m8fjm8/1/)**

**ADDITIONAL NOTE:**

If you need to load Bootstrap and jQuery in your html page, not in jsfiddle you have to link the corresponding resources inside your `<head>` tag in your html page.

For example, using MaxCDN links you can use the following code:

```html
<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <!-- html code ...-->
</body>
```

**IMPORTANT:** Make sure you include the js files in that exact order, jQuery first then Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Navbar Mockup</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>  </div>
</nav>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`